# Тонкая стрелка посредством css

Tags: css, hover

Ребята, нужно чтобы при наведении менялся цвет стрелки, но она идет картинкой. Подумываю сделать стрелку.

Вот начало:

```
.click-left h4:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 400px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
}
```

Нужно получить такую [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении - черная. Реализовала только тонкую линию, а как стрелки сделать не знаю.
Помогите в решении.

Comment: Возьмите лучше шрифтовую иконку: https://fontawesome.com/icons или попросите у дизайнера в формате `svg`

Comment: Можно ещё поискать в символах юникода, там довольно много стрелок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.click-left h4 {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 400px;
  width: 56px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

h4:hover .arrow,
h4:hover .arrow:before,
h4:hover .arrow:after {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="click-left">
  <h4>Click me<span class="arrow"></span></h4>
</div>
```